# MySQL/PHP: Can't add full string to table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store some information from a session in to a DB via PHP. My PHP code is as follows:

```
if($_SESSION['order']['quote']['coupon_amt'] > 0){
    $cpnArgs = array(
            'coupon_id' => $_SESSION['order']['quote']['coupon'],
            'user_id' => $_SESSION['js_user_id'],
            'order_id' => $_SESSION['order']['id'],
          );
    $db->add_coupon_uses($cpnArgs);
}
```

This is being passed onto the function which is:

```
function add_coupon_uses($args) {
    return $this->add_row(REGION_PREFIX."Coupon_Uses", $args);
}
```

The add_row function, which is standardized and works quite well for everything else, however, when i'm trying to pass values, I only get the digits of the coupon code, not the full string.

The Column is set to VARCHAR(50). I've:

```
print_r($_SESSION['order']['quote']['coupon']);
```

to verify that the value is correct which is being passed - it is.

Does anyone see something glaring that I do not?

---

EDIT:

`$db->add_coupon_uses` just sends the function to a library that contains function `add_coupon_uses`

The value is 5 characters long, and values of print_r would be as follows

```
print_r ($_SESSION['order']['quote']['coupon']); --> 50OFF
print_r ($_SESSION['js_user_id']);               --> 27592
print_r ($_SESSION['order']['id']);              --> 3045858920
```

I guess I was just curious if there was an obvious issue here since i can't figure it out. Perhaps something so glaring that everyone can see it but I can't because I've stared at the code for so long.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post where the data is being inserted. There's not enough here to help you.

Comment: Sorry, without telling us something about `$db` you cannot expect us to help here...

Comment: I suppose you checked the value is not more than 50 characters

Comment: Also you have a comma after the last entry being added to $cpnArgs could that be your issue